# How to empty a textbox on another textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have two textboxes in asp.net page. I want to check onkeypress or any other event of 1st Textbox and if user remove text in it then text of 2nd textbox should also be removed. 
I tried different methods on onkeypress , onkeyup and onkeydown but it is not working. 

 Unfortunately i dont have the code right now. Can any one please provide a javascript method for this task.

```
I know it can be done on textchange event of textbox in codebehind but i want it to be done on client side.
```

Further more there is also an AJAX AutoCompleteExtender associated with the textbox.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input type="text" id="text1" onKeyUp="myFunction(event)" />
 <input type="text" id="text2" />

<script type="text/javascript">

   function myFunction(event){
         if(document.getElementById('text1').value == ""){
             document.getElementById('text2').value = "";
         }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you looking for something like this

```
<input id="txt1" type="text"  />
<input id="txt2" type="text" />
```

if you need to remove text only if textbox1 value is empty

```
$('#txt1').keyup(function() {
     var str = $('#txt1').val();
    if(str==''){
     $('#txt2').val(str );
    }
});
```

if need to keep same text remove the if condition

jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VFYZw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" Runat= "Server" onkeyup="javascript:keyUP(this);" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" Runat= "Server" ></asp:TextBox>

var txt2= document.getelementByID('txt2.ClientID');

function keyUP(txt) 
{
    if(txt.value == '')
    {
        txt2.value == '';
    }   
}
```

thanks